# how to convert dataframe to RDD and don't change partition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For some reason i have to convert `RDD` to `dataframe`,then do something with `dataframe`,but my interface is `RDD`,so i have to convert `dataframe` to `RDD`，when i use `df.rdd`,the partition change to 1,so i have to `repartition` and `sortBy` RDD,Is there any cleaner solution ?thanks!
this is my try:

```
    val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8),4)
    val partition=rdd.getNumPartitions
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(m_sparkCtx)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val df=rdd.toDF()
    df.rdd.zipWithIndex().sortBy(x => {x._2}, true, partition).map(x => {x._1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitions should remain the same when you convert the DataFrame to an RDD.
For example when the rdd of 4 partitions is converted to DF and back the RDD the partitions of the RDD remains same as shown below.

```
scala> val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8),4)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[11] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> val partition=rdd.getNumPartitions
partition: Int = 4

scala> val df=rdd.toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df.rdd.getNumPartitions
res1: Int = 4

scala> df.withColumn("col2", lit(10)).rdd.getNumPartitions
res1: Int = 4
```

Comment: ok,df.withColumn function may change partition to 1，Is there any cleaner solution

Comment: Can you elaborate on "df.withColumn function may change partition to 1" given you accepted the answer?

Comment: @mentongwu `df.withColumn` should also not change the number of partitions. see the updated answer.